# Create a new folder with the folder name from a text box value in Excel VB

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a new folder using an Excel VB form. When I enter a text in the textbox and click on *Submit* button it should create the folder, and the folder name must be what is entered in the textbox.

I dont know anything about coding, just tried a code like this but it throws errors.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim Newfolder As String
  Dim path As String
  Newfolder = TextBox1.text
  path = " E:\projects\"
  ChDir (path)
  MkDir (Newfolder)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim Newfolder As String, path As String

  Newfolder = Sheet1.TextBox1.Text
  path = "E:\projects\" & Newfolder

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(path) Then .CreateFolder path
    End With

End Sub
```

If you get an error, ensure you have permission to create a folder in the location defined in `path`. Also, be careful not to include a space before the drive path - `E:\projects\`